# Mocha Testing logout controller throwing invalid username

Tags: mocha.js

Please I need help on this, I am trying to text my logout route blow with mocha

```
// @route GET /auth/logout
// @desc Logout user
// @access Public
exports.logoutUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  res.clearCookie("token");

  res.send("You have successfully logged out");
});
```

Here is the mocha funtion for testing using expect and supertest libraries

```
describe("GET /auth/logout", () => {
  before((done) => {
    User.create({
      usename: "kanban",
      email: "test@kanban.com",
      password: "123456",
    });
  });

  it("should remove cookies and log user out", (done) => {
    request(app)
      .post("/auth/login")
      .send({
        username: "kanban",
        email: "test@kanban",
        password: "123456",
      })
      .expect(200)
      .get("/auth/logout")
      .expect((res) => {
        expect(res.headers["set-cookies"]).toBeNull();
      })
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) return done(err);
        done();
      });
  });
  after((done) => {
    User.deleteMany({}).then(() => done());
  });
});
```

However it is throwing the below Error

*GET /auth/logout
Error: user validation failed: username: Path `username` is required.
Error: user validation failed: username: Path `username` is required.*

I would really be grateful if you could help me figure this out :)

Answer (score 2):

I will answer my own question after debugging, first I need to log in separately and then expect the cookies not to be null after that, then I called logout. this is the proper way :)

```
describe("GET /auth/logout", () => {
  before((done) => {
    User.create({
      username: "kanban",
      email: "test@kanban.com",
      password: "123456",
    }).then(() => done());
  });

  it("should remove cookies and log user out", (done) => {
    request(app)
      .post("/auth/login")
      .send({
        username: "kanban",
        email: "test@kanban.com",
        password: "123456",
      })
      .expect(200)
      .expect((res) => {
        expect(res.headers["set-cookies"]).not.toBeNull();
      });

    request(app)
      .get("/auth/logout")
      .expect((res) => {
        expect(res.headers["set-cookies"]).toBeUndefined();
      })
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) return done(err);
        done();
      });
  });
  after((done) => {
    User.deleteMany({}).then(() => done());
  });
});
```